# Bug: cannot upvote

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting

I am trying to upvote Beofett's answer on [How should I help my 9years old son to get back on TAG program](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/how-should-i-help-my-9years-old-son-to-get-back-on-tag-program)

The first time I did it, I got a red box with an error message saying 'error processing request, try again later' or something similar.

I have tried again since then (it was a few hours ago), and I have not been successful.

I am using IE 11 (latest version) Windows 8 (desktop).

I did close the tab with SE in, but I did NOT close the browser window, I just reopened a new tab and tried again

UPDATE: closing and reopening the browser did not help. I was able to upvote successfully in Chrome.

Comment: note: when I submitted this question I got an error, resubmitting (clicking the button again) helped

Comment: More notes: Happens occasionally, both up and downvotes on questions, answers and comments. On multiple SE sites.

Comment: I have very consistently had issues using SE with IE. Waiting (~30-60 seconds) after opening the question sometimes reduced the chance of an error. Months ago I simply gave up and only use Chrome or Firefox now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer relevant (old bug post).

Answer (score 1):

I can't post this as a comment, so I am posting as an answer.  I had not upvoted his answer as of reading this, so I opened IE 11, logged in, visited the URL, opened the dev tools, then upvoted.

The vote went through w/o an error.

The Request was sent to `/posts/14990/vote/2` and the body was populated with (obv I have corrupted the key with the F's):

```
fkey=783b6aFFFFFFFFFFFFFcadeacd40e86e054
```

The cookies sent in the request were (codes hidden):

```
_ga=HIDDEN; __qca=HIDDEN; _gat=1; gauthed=1; parentinguser=t=HIDDEN&s=HIDDEN
```

The JSON response received was (nothing changed as it couldn't be a security risk):

```
{"Success":true,"Warning":false,"NewScore":4,"Message":"","LastVoteTypeId":2,"Refresh":false,"Transient":false}
```

In the developer Emulation settings, the values are:

> Document mode: Edge (Default)
>
> Browser profile: Desktop
>
> User agent string: Default

I hope that helps!  Maybe going to another question you want to upvote, hitting F12 and checking out the tabs to see if the settings are the same will help -- sometimes people I know turn on compatibility mode causing things to break.

If I can provide further data, pls let me know.